# Error when adding a ScriptManager to page

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I am using VS2010, .Net 4.  I am trying to add a ScriptManager to my page, so I can reference an AJAX Enabled WCF Service.  When I add the ScriptManager control to my page and view it - I get the error shown below.  I have no clue how to resolve it.  I get the error by simply putting the control on my page (not reference the WCF Service).

Error seen when "viewing source":

```
(script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=cN6E-bUIIAhb0PYSsbqev2ndhi3W3ltVtHjrJ-T5yBfO3jQBEHWjU39PLAybm-JIxwU4s59EhJFweLHmABl1zA2yo8fKhHYHGS7RTy1fhECuWqXbMMy5aCuSlqHbfp3advQcwp11SqaDwkvU1YN6Bw2&amp;t=ffffffffbd2983fc" type="text/javascript")(/script)

(script type="text/javascript") 
//(![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]])
(/script)
```

Actually, my problem is that I am not able to access the service.  I am referencing it inside the ScriptManager and have the javascript code in place, but Firefox is reporting that it cannot find it.  Says it is not defined.  I do not know how to test this or determine where it is failing.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry.  Posted more the my original notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **Ajax client-side framework failed to load** message, you get it because ScriptManager fail to load the Ajax Toolkit extensions.

Download it from: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx